# Javascript to send data from if/else to google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

First time posting a question, hope there is an answer:

I am a teacher and use Google Forms to create quizzes. I have been working on a script to automatically grade the script and I have it working. This script mails the grade to the student. What I need now is a way to keep that grade in the spreadsheet. So what I am looking for is a way to send that score into the correct cell of the Google Spreadsheet.

Here is my script so far:

```
function GoogleStudent(e) {  
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var Fname = e.values[1];
var Lname = e.values[2];
var Semail = e.values[3];  
var subject = "Test Grade";
//var sgrade = e.value[15]  
var emailbody = "Thank You, " + Fname + " " + Lname + ",for submitting your form";

var q1  =   e.values[4]
var q2  =   e.values[5]
var q3  =   e.values[6]
var q4  =   e.values[7]
var q5  =   e.values[8]
var q6  =   e.values[9]
var q7  =   e.values[10]
var q8  =   e.values[11]
var q9  =   e.values[12]
var q10 =   e.values[13]


var score = 0;
if(q1 == "Prezi"){var a1 = "correct"; score++;}else {var a1 = "Nope";}
if(q2 == "All the above"){var a2 = "correct"; score++;}else {var a2 = "Nope";}
if(q3 == "Yes"){var a3 = "correct";  score++;}else {var a3 = "Nope";}
if(q4 == "Popplet"){var a4 = "correct";  score++;}else {var a4 = "Nope";}
if(q5 == "Zondle"){var a5 = "correct";  score++;}else {var a5 = "Nope";}
if(q6 == "Yellow"){var a6 = "correct";  score++;}else {var a6 = "Nope";}
if(q7 == "When the joke is not connected to the content"){var a7 = "correct";  score++;}else {var a7 = "Nope";}
if(q8 == "False"){var a8 = "correct";  score++;}else {var a8 = "Nope";}
if(q9 == "False"){var a9 = "correct";  score++;}else {var a9 = "Nope";}
if(q10 == "Prezi"){var a10 = "correct";  score++;}else {var a10 = "Nope";}




var htmlBody = "<img src= 'http://frbonnie.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/thanks2.jpg' `enter code here`alt='Thank you' height='50' width='70' align='middle'>" +
",<b style='color:#00FF00;'>TeacherName</b>, for submitting your' " +  
"<img src= 'http://velocityagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/go.jpg' alt='Google' height='50' width='70' align='middle'></a> Form<br />" +
"<br />" +  
"Your Grade for this Test is - " + score +  
"<br />" +  
//(content removed for protection)



  var optAdvancedArgs = {htmlBody: htmlBody};

MailApp.sendEmail(Semail, subject, emailbody, optAdvancedArgs);
MailApp.sendEmail("**myemail**", subject, emailbody, optAdvancedArgs);

}
```

This script works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: A clever student could cheat pretty easily..

Comment: It seems like you are looking for the Google Spreadsheets API. Check out this documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell. As mambrow said, though, any student with a basic understanding of JavaScript could easily cheat your system.